# Why do I get a fatal error when clicking on the permissions tab in admin/people?

Tags: 7

Steps to reproduce:

1. Log in as administrator
2. Click on `People`
3. Click on the `Permissions` tab

This navigates to `admin/people/permissions`. Here is the complete source code for that page:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2048 bytes) in /.../includes/common.inc on line 6300
```

Why am I getting this error and what can I do about it?

**Notes**:

- my `php.ini` file contains the following line: `memory_limit = 128M`
- `.../sites/default/settings.php` contains the following line: `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`
- If I go to `Reports/Status report` and scroll down to `PHP memory limit`, it says `128M`

Comment: are you using the default/settings.php or you are running a multisite? maybe you have a settings.php other than the one in the default folder

Comment: @ninjascorner  
You were right, I am running a multisite and only the settings.php in sites/default/ had the memory_limit instruction. I added it to sites/mysite/ and the problem went away. Would you like to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running multisite, you probably need to modify your settings.php on each sites.